# Android::Kotlin. Image Slider returning empty image view

Tags: android, kotlin

```
class whatever : AppCompatActivity() {


    private lateinit var viewPager3: ViewPager2

    private lateinit var docimagelist: ArrayList<String>

    private lateinit var databaseHelper: DocDetailsDatabaseHelper

    private lateinit var imageSliderAdapter5: ImageSliderAdapter2

    


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.whatever_image_slider)

        val b = intent.extras
        val id = b!!.getString("id")

        viewPager3 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager5)



        databaseHelper= DocDetailsDatabaseHelper(this)

        docimagelist=databaseHelper.getImagesByName("id")



        viewPager3 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager5)



        imageSliderAdapter5 = ImageSliderAdapter2(this, docimagelist)

        viewPager3.adapter = imageSliderAdapter5

        viewPager3.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        viewPager3.setCurrentItem(viewPager3.currentItem + 1, true)


    }
}
```

'docimagelist' contains a array of names of images. Images are there in drawable, but upon starting it, it is returning a blank image view. Im pretty new to this, sure im  getting something wrong, cant figure out what. can i pass the values of docimagelist to somehow create a list of drawable images?

Answer (score 0):

I think the part that loads image from imageName is incorrect.

You can use this code:

```
fun getResourceIdByName(name: String): Int {
    return resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", packageName)
}
```

and in onCreate function:

```
val drawableList = ArrayList<Drawable>()

for (imageName in docimagelist) {
    val resourceId = getResourceIdByName(imageName)
    val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, resourceId)
    drawableList.add(drawable!!)
}

imageSliderAdapter5 = ImageSliderAdapter2(this, drawableList)
```

Well, it will load images.
Please try and let me know if it works at your side.

Comment: imageSliderAdapter5 = ImageSliderAdapter2(this, drawableList)

ImageSliderAdapter2 takes string as parameter but now im trying to pass drawable